# Symfony Workflow - check if user can access

Tags: php, symfony, workflow

I have a simple workflow for my posts blog.

```yaml
framework:
    workflows: 
        post_publishing:
            type: 'state_machine'
            marking_store:
                type: 'method'
                property: 'state'
            supports:
                - App\Entity\Post
            initial_marking: pending
            places:
                - pending
                - draft
                - published
                - archived
            transitions:
                to_draft:
                    guard: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
                    from: pending
                    to: draft
                to_publish:
                    guard: "is_granted('ROLE_USER')"
                    from: draft
                    to: published
                to_archived:
                    guard: "is_granted('ROLE_USER')"
                    from: [published, draft]
                    to: archived
```

The bundle allows me to check that a state can be given by a defined profile.
Symfony allows me to check that an article, whatever its status, can be read or not, according to a defined profile.

I want my entities to be accessible to profiles depending on the state.

For example: An unauthenticated user can only read published posts, an authenticated user, draft and published posts, while an admin can read published, draft and archived posts.

Can we include this in the workflow bundle settings?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. If you put is_granted ROLE_ADMIN that mean only ADMIN could access. So unauthenticated users will not access

Comment: So what is your issue ? using guard to protect transition works, but if you mean unauthenticated users should not be able to access/view your Post, its another matter. Be more precise to explain what you are trying to accomplish and what is not working.

Comment: The bundle allows me to check that a state can be given by a defined profile.
Symfony allows me to check that an article, whatever its status, can be read or not, according to a defined profile.

I want my entities to be accessible to profiles depending on the state.
For example: An unauthenticated user can only read published posts, an authenticated user, draft and published posts, while an admin can read published, draft and archived posts.

I was hoping this would be configurable from the workflow bundle.